# How to use dotLottie in react native?

Tags: react-native, gif, lottie

How can i use the dotlottie in react native. I have compressed the json file to dotlottie file but how can i render this dotlottie in react native.

```
https://dotlottie.io/
```

Is there is any way to achieve this.

Or is there is any other way to reduce the json file sizes ?